# Output a 2 column table to a three column query

Tags: sql-server-2012

Hi I have a Table with 2 columns, one column for the employeename and another column for shift,  below is a sample.

```
EmployeeName          Shift
John                    1
Peter                   1
Mary                    2
Mike                    1
John                    2
Paul                    2
Mary                    1
```

I want to output it to query with 3 columns and count the number of shifts as show below:

```
EmployeeName         Shift1            Shift2
John                   1                 1
Peter                  1                 0
Mary                   1                 1
Mike                   1                 0
Paul                   0                 1
```

Comment: (What do you want to happen if there are two rows with `John, 1`?)

Comment: John i have a table similar to these and need to count two conditions, so queries have different where clause need to combine them in 1 result.

Answer (score 4):

In SQL Server 2012 you can use the new `IIF()` function:

```
SELECT EmployeeName, 
  Shift1 = COUNT(IIF(Shift=1,1,NULL)),
  Shift2 = COUNT(IIF(Shift=2,1,NULL))
FROM dbo.tablename
GROUP BY EmployeeName;
```

This is just shorthand for a `CASE` expression, so on older versions you could do it this way:

```
SELECT EmployeeName, 
  Shift1 = COUNT(CASE WHEN Shift = 1 THEN 1 END),
  Shift2 = COUNT(CASE WHEN Shift = 2 THEN 1 END)
FROM dbo.tablename
GROUP BY EmployeeName;
```

You can also use `PIVOT`:

```
SELECT EmployeeName, Shift1 = [1], Shift2 = [2] 
FROM dbo.TableName AS t
PIVOT (COUNT(Shift) FOR Shift IN ([1],[2])) AS p;
```

Now, none of these seems to produce the results in the same order you've defined in the question, and I don't know it's possible to produce that order reliably given the sample data you've shown.

<kbd>[# SQLfiddle demo #](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6e04d/1)</kbd>

Comment: Actually 1 and 2 works well, the pivot i can not get to work properly.. a million thanks, im trying to figure this one out for the past 2 days, btw i am new in sql

Answer (score 0):

```
select EmployeeName, max(shift1) as shift1, max(shift2) as shift2
from (
    select EmployeeName
         , case when shift = 1 then 1 else 0 end as shift1
         , case when shift = 2 then 1 else 0 end as shift2
    from T
) as t2
group by EmployeeName
```